# How to combine lists?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists. I want to make some operation of this lists. But I do not know tho exactly function.
Question:

```
integerList = { 1  , 2   , 3}
realList    = { 1.5, 2.5 , 3.5}
```

**1**
Join the two list. first integer datas and secondly real datas

```
combineList1 = {{1 , 2, 3}  ,{ 1.5, 2.5,3.5} }
```

**2** 
make an one list first integer datas and seconly real datas but only use CombineList1 (not use integerList  and realList)

```
 combineList2 = {1, 1.5 , 2, 2.5 ,3,3.5}
```

**3**
make a pairs list at the two list. first integer datas and secondly real datas

```
combineList3 = {{1 , 1.5} ,{2, 2.5}  ,{3,3.5} }
```

**4** 
make an one list first integer datas and seconly real datas but only use CombineList3 (not use integerList  and realList)

```
 combineList4 = {1, 1.5 , 2, 2.5 ,3,3.5}
```

I need to known these functions.
thank you very much

Comment: Also, two important points: 1) you **cannot** use _ in variable names in _Mathematica_, underscores stand for `Blank` patterns. 2) Try to stick with camelCase, since all built-in functions are Capitalized in _Mathematica_.

Comment: Fixed the question for clear understand

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
integerList = {1, 2, 3}
realList = {1.5, 2.5, 3.5}
```

1. `combineList1 = {integerList, realList}`

   > {{1, 2, 3}, {1.5, 2.5, 3.5}}
2. `combineList2 = Flatten[Transpose[combineList1]]`

   > {1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5}
3. `combineList3 = Transpose[{integerList, realList}]`

   > {{1, 1.5}, {2, 2.5}, {3, 3.5}}
4. `combineList4 = Flatten[combineList3]`

   > {1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5}

You might want to also check out [`Riffle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Riffle.html) and [`Catenate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Catenate.html).

Comment: Thank you very much. it is done.

Comment: For (2) also `Flatten[combineList1, {2, 1}]`

Answer (score 2):

Note there is a convention: Never begin your own variables or functions with an uppercase letter.

```
il = Range[10]
rl = Table[i, {i, 1.5, 10, 1}]
cl1= Riffle[il, rl]
i2 = Partition[il, 2]
r2 = Partition[rl, 2]
cl2=Flatten[Riffle[i2, r2]]
```